# Copy Local = false ignored when I Publish my ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, deployment, assemblies, publish

I have an ASP.NET Web Application that has several references set.  I have Copy Local set to False for several of them, but when I Publish my application it copies the .dlls anyway.  How can I turn that off for good?  The dlls are registered in the GAC on the web server and I want to make sure that those are references instead of local copies.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the assemblies registered in the GAC on your local developer machine? If not, register them in the GAC there and it should honor your copy local settings when you build the solution there.

Comment: Additionally, make sure the files aren't actually included as part of your project, and it's just referencing them.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I don't recall a publish option to prevent local copy of the referenced assemblies. You might have to remove them manually or write some script or batch files to automate it.

Maybe this article can help: http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Deploy-ASP.NET.aspx

Comment: I add a reference to my web application project, I view the properties of that reference, and I set Copy Local to false.  That *should* keep it from copying to the bin folder.

Comment: That is not for deployment or publish purpose (I would think), but for local development and debug run.

Comment: I hv added an url in my post to an article which might help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Web Deployment Project for this. You can configure that specific files will be deleted after the Build process.

For a Web Deployment Project you need at least VS 2008 SP1.