# Copy Local = false is ignored on publish with new Configuration

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, publish

I've created 2 new configurations in Visual Studio 2010 to use different web.config (by transformation).
After publishing I got an error on a specific DLL.
When checking the bin-folder I noticed that the dll was in there, even though *Copy Local* was set to *false*.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032318/copy-local-false-ignored-when-i-publish-my-asp-net-web-application) that stated that the dll had to be registered in the GAC.
I've checked it, and it was there, with the correct version.

After investigating a bit more I found out that the dll was only published in the newly created configurations. When I published under "Debug" or "Release" the dll was omitted (as expected).

Is there an explanation for this odd behaviour?

**UPDATE:**

Still no answer found, but the weird thing here is that the "Copy local = false"-dll is not always  published. Although I didn't change anything to the references, it wasn't copied with a publish a few days ago. Today it was again in the published Bin-folder.